# Баг в работе Javascript для IOS в Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Я понимаю что вопрос размыт.  Но возможно кто-то стыкался, и ответ очевиденю
Есть код который перезагружает iframe если документ не загружен.  Он отлично работает везде кроме  мобильное  версии Safari.  Возможно в коде
есть что-то, что очевидно может не отрабатывать для Safari мобильной версии.
Буду признателен за ваши идеи. Или предложения как это переделать.

```
refreshIFrame = function() {
  var iframe = $('#iframe_preview')[0]
  var try_count = 0

  try {
    if (try_count >= 5 || !iframe.contentDocument) throw 'Not loaded'

    var repeat = setInterval(refresh, 3000)
    function refresh() {
      try {
        if (try_count >= 5 || !iframe.contentDocument) throw 'Not loaded'
      } catch(_) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
      }
      iframe.src = iframe.src;
      try_count++
    }
  } catch(_) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если в остальных работает, то можете попробовать написать что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
var refreshIFrame = function() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_preview'); //id должен быть уникальным
  vat _iframeContent = iframe ? iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument 
  : iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : null;
  var try_count = 0;

  try {
    if (try_count >= 5 || !_iframeContent ) throw 'Not loaded'

    var repeat = setInterval(refresh, 3000)
    function refresh() {
      try {
        if (try_count >= 5 || !_iframeContent ) throw 'Not loaded'
      } catch(_) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
      }
      iframe.src = iframe.src + '';
      try_count++
    }
  } catch(_) {}
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось использовать ваш код . В это строке "  var _iframeContent = iframe ? iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument 
  : iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow : null;"  присутсвует какая-та синтаксическая ошибка, и я к сожелению не могу понять какая.